# Error 429 when trying to loop through Hubspot Deals API JSON

Tags: google-apps-script, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I'm trying to get all the deals in my Hubspot API into a Google Sheet. The following Google App Script worked fine when the deal count was under 250. Now that I have more than 250 deals in my pipeline I'm getting 429 errors, 'Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.', and other errors.

```html
function getDeals() {
   // Prepare authentication to Hubspot
   
   var service = getService();
   var headers = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ service.getAccessToken()}};
   
   // Prepare pagination
   // Hubspot lets you take max 250 deals per request.
   // We need to make multiple request until we get all the deals.
   
   var keep_going = true;
   var offset = 0;
   var deals = Array();
   while(keep_going) {
      
      // We’ll take three properties from the deals: the source, the stage, the amount of the deal
      
      var url = API_URL + "/deals/v1/deal/paged?&includeAssociations=true&properties=dealstage&properties=source&properties=amount&properties=dealname&properties=num_associated_contacts&limit=250&offset&properties=hubspot_owner_id&limit=250&offset="+offset;
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
      var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      Logger.log(result.deal)
      
      // Are there any more results, should we stop the pagination
      
      keep_going = result.hasMore;
      offset = result.offset;
      
      // For each deal, we take the stageId, source, amount, dealname, num_associated_contacts & hubspot_owner_id
      
      result.deals.forEach(function(deal) {
         var stageId = (deal.properties.hasOwnProperty("dealstage")) ? deal.properties.dealstage.value : "unknown";
         var source = (deal.properties.hasOwnProperty("source")) ? deal.properties.source.value : "unknown";
         var amount = (deal.properties.hasOwnProperty("amount")) ? deal.properties.amount.value : 0;
         var dealname = (deal.properties.hasOwnProperty("dealname")) ? deal.properties.dealname.value : "unknown";
         var hubspot_owner_id = (deal.properties.hasOwnProperty("hubspot_owner_id")) ? deal.properties.hubspot_owner_id.value : "unknown";
         var num_associated_contacts = (deal.properties.hasOwnProperty("num_associated_contacts")) ? deal.properties.num_associated_contacts.value : "unknown";
         deals.push([stageId,source,amount,dealname,num_associated_contacts,hubspot_owner_id]);
      });
   }
   return deals;
}
```

Comment: How often do you call this? That will govern the `UrlFetchApp` quota error. Also, your URL has two uses of `offset` - one after `&limit=250`, and one at the end. That may be related to your 429's, i.e. HubSpot's API probably takes the first value for a parameter, so the offset is always 0. Have you checked that you get different items on the second call?

Comment: Hi tehhowch, the script is triggered every 15 minutes, which I believe is way under the limit for G Suite users. Should I get rid of one of the uses of `offset` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is from the multiple specification of both the `offset` and `limit` URL parameters in your `url`:

```
"...&limit=250&offset&...&limit=250&offset=" + offset;
```

HubSpot's API may only expect a single value for certain keywords (such as limit and offset), which would mean you are always accessing only the first page of results - if more than one page exists, you would never stop calling this function until you exhaust your `UrlFetchApp` quota and the script exits via an unhandled exception, as `result.hasMore` would always be true.

I would rewrite your script to use a do-while loop (and also to simplify your property extraction).

```
function getDeals() {
  // Prepare authentication to Hubspot
  const service = getService();
  const fetchParams = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ service.getAccessToken()}
  };

  // Properties to collect from each deal:
  const desiredProps = [
    "dealstage",
    "source",
    "amount",
    "dealname",
    "num_associated_contacts",
    "hubspot_owner_id"
  ];
  const deals = [];

  // Hubspot lets you take max 250 deals per request.
  // Make multiple requests until we get all the deals.
  var offset = 0;
  var remainingPages = 100; // just in case.
  const url = API_URL + "/deals/v1/deal/paged?&includeAssociations=true&properties=dealstage&properties=source&properties=amount&properties=dealname&properties=num_associated_contacts&properties=hubspot_owner_id"
      + "&limit=250&offset=";

  do {
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + offset, fetchParams);
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    offset = result.offset;

    var pageDealInfo = result.deals.map(function (deal) {
      var dealInfo = desiredProperties.map(function (propName) {
        var val = deal.properties[propName];
        return (val === undefined ? "Unknown" : val;
      });
      /** add other things to dealInfo that aren't members of deal.properties
      dealInfo.push(deal.<something>);
       */
      return dealInfo;
    });

    // Add all the info for all the deals from this page of results.
    if (pageDealInfo.length)
      Array.prototype.push.apply(deals, pageDealInfo);
  } while (result.hasMore && --remainingPages);

  if (!remainingPages)
    console.warn({message: "Stopped deal queries due to own page limit - more deals exist!", currentOffset: offset, gatheredDealCount: deals.length});
  else
    console.log({message: "Finished deal queries", totalDeals: deals.length});

  return deals;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'm sure this will fix the issue! as for the Google fetch quota, I will have to wait until it resets, right?

Answer (score 1):

As per HubSpots API Usage Guidelines:

> HubSpot has the following limits in place for API requests:
>
> - 10 requests per second.
> - 40,000 requests per day. This daily limit resets at midnight based on    the time zone setting of the HubSpot account.

---

Source: https://developers.hubspot.com/apps/api_guidelines

There is a maximum size limit of 250 records that can be fetched in the deals API.

You should do the following

> In addition to the list of deals, each request will also return two
>   values, offset and hasMore. If hasMore is true, you'll need to make
>   another request, using the offset to get the next page of deal
>   records.

The `offset` param in the next request should be the value that was returned in the previous requests response.

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks for the answer. I've tried doing that. But apparently I'm missing something in the script and I can't figure out what is it.